# How to determine if a nested list structure is the same as another, but with elements exchanged for new ones

Tags: python, permutation

Let's say we have two nested lists: `L1 = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]` and `L2 = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]`

The question is, does there exist a bijection between the integers in one list and the integers in the other list which transforms `L1` into `L2`?  For `L1` and `L2` given above, the answer is yes.

BIJECTION:

- old `0` becomes new `1`
- old `1` becomes new `2`
- old `2`becomes new `3`

Recall our nested list `L1 = [[0, 1], [0, 2]]`. If we apply the mapping described above, then we get `L2 = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]` Therefore, `foo(L1, L2)` should return `True`. `foo` is the name of the equality operator we are trying to implement.

Also, order does not matter. Each list should be treated as a mathematical "set."

Some examples are shown below:

Left list: `[[2, 1], [3, 1]]`
Right list: `[[1, 2], [1, 3]]` : True
`foo(left,right)` returns `True`
**why?**
order doesn't matter

Left list: `[[2, 1], [3, 1]]`
Right list: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`
`foo(left,right)` returns `False`
**why?**
Two integers inside of the left list are the same, but all integers inside of the right list are different from each-other.

`left`= `[[2, 1], [3, 1]]`
`right` = `[[0, 1], [0, 1]]`
`foo(left, right)` returns `False`
**why?**
the right list contains only 2 distinct integers (`0` and `1`). The left list contains 3 distinct integers (`1`, `2`, `3`)

Some longer examples are shown below:

Original list: `[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [0, 1, 2]]`

A1: `[[4, 1], [4, 0], [1, 0], [1, 3], [4, 1, 0]]` : True

A2: `[[4, 1], [4, 0], [1, 3], [1, 0], [4, 0, 1]]` : True

B: `[[1, 2], [3, 1], [2, 4], [1, 4], [2, 4, 1]]` : True

C: `[[3, 2], [5, 2], [5, 0], [0, 2], [5, 0, 2]]` : True

D: `[[5, 2], [5, 2], [3, 0], [0, 2], [5, 0, 2]]` : False

E: `[[3, 0], [0, 3], [5, 0], [0, 2], [5, 0, 2]]` : False

Bijection for Example `A1`:

```
ORIGINAL  A
 0        4
 1        1
 2        0
 3        3
```

`A2` is simply a reordering of `A1`

In example B, 2 and 4 are playing the same role as 0 and 2 in the original list. 1 is in the same role in both lists, as is 3.

In example C, 0 and 5 are playing the same role as 0 and 2 in the original list, 2 is playing the same role as 1 in the original list, and 3 is playing the same role in both lists.
In example D, there are two sub-lists which are the same ([5, 2]), while the original list has no repeating sub-lists.
In example E, 0 is in all four length-2 sub-lists, while in the original list, no number is in all four length-2 sub-lists.

Here is the code I have from my attempt, however it does not work when a low number (like 0) is exchanged for one of the largest numbers in the lists (like say 4). When it does the sorting, it fails to recognize that the 4 is playing the same role as the 0. Since low numbers can be exchanged for high numbers, sorting will not work.

```py
def CheckUnique(configs, newconfig):
    sortednewconfig = sorted([sorted(i) for i in newconfig])
    presentnumbers = []
    canonicalnewconfig = []
    for sub in sortednewconfig:
        for i in sub:
            if i not in presentnumbers:
                presentnumbers.append(i)
    for sub in sortednewconfig:
        cansub = []
        for i in sub:
            cansub.append(presentnumbers.index(i))
        canonicalnewconfig.append(cansub)
    if canonicalnewconfig not in configs:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: How is `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` not "the same structure" as `[[0, 1], [0, 2]]`? Both lists consist of two lists of two elements each.

Comment: In the first list, one element, 0, is in both sub-lists. That is not true for [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

Comment: Okay, so it seems like you have some conditions that go beyond lists having "the same structure". You need to come up with a clear, unambiguous description of these conditions -- I suspect that this exercise will get you most of the way to working code. :)

Comment: @duskwuff Did you stop reading the question after the second sentence? The third sentence explains that there has to be an element in common.

Comment: @Barmar That doesn't fully explain it, at least not to me. The second sub-lists in the inputs for the first example -- `[0, 2]` and `[1, 3]` -- have no elements in common.

Comment: If I understand it, you just have to test whether at least one of the numbers in the original list can be found in each of the sublists in the list being tested.

Comment: So `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` doesn't match because neither 3 nor 4 are in the original list.

Comment: @duskwuff I used "shape" to describe the size and number of sub-lists. "structure" is meant to mean how the sub-lists are related by what they have in common.

Comment: @Barmar The elements can be exchanged for new ones as in the title, no elements need to match. In the first basic example, the structure is this: Both sub-lists have exactly one element in common (and thus the other element in each sub-list are unique from each other). It gets more complicated for the longer example, but if you compare how each number appears, the numbers appear in the same structure, despite being different numbers.

Comment: In your expanded explanation, it's really hard to tell when you're talking about elements of the original list or the list being tested.

Comment: OK, so the first pair of lists matches because the original list is in the form `[[x, y], [x, z]]` (x = 0, y = 1, z = 2) and so is the test list (x = 1, y = 2, z = 3). But order doesn't matter, so it would also match if it were `[[x, y], [z, x]]`. Am I getting it?

Comment: Is this a programming challenge or is there some real application of this?

Comment: @Barmar I am using numbers (1, 2, 3..) to refer to the integers in the list, and words (one, two three) when referring to multiple occurrences. From your last comment it seems you are getting it yes. It is from a real application, well I am not getting paid for it, but it is a math-related coding project I am working on. I am trying to find a way to uniquely classify the possible configurations in [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A250001). It has to do with how many ways circles overlap. The issue is which circle we call "circle 1" and which circle we call "circle 4" is an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @Barmar Without this type of check, I grossly over-count the possible configurations. I have come across this type of problem before, where how we number things is an arbitrary choice, but despite our numberings, there is a an underlying structure. Different numberings with the same underlying structure should be counted as a single entity, since the numbering is arbitrary. However, in my code, I have to number them to keep track of which one is which.

Comment: I suggest you sort each sublist, then canonicalize the values to consecutive numbers. Then just compare the two lists.

Comment: So `[[2, 1], [3, 4]]` first changes to `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` when you sort the sublists. Then you replace `1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3`. Then when you compare with the original list, they match.

Comment: @Barmar [Here is an illustrative example](https://imgur.com/QCbt6GH) of the things I am trying to distinguish. I made it in ms paint so cut me some slack. If it helps I know the total number of circles, so the largest integer index value is bounded by that, it is not swapping the numbers out for any arbitrarily large number.

Comment: I believe you when you say it has a real application, I don't need the details. Does my suggested approach sound right?

Comment: @Barmar I believe so, I am implementing it now to test it, but I think that works. I'd upvote your answer, but it is not a top level answer. Thanks.

Comment: It was just a general approach, not a real answer. If you get it working, post your own answer. If you can't get it working, post your code.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately it doesn't work. It felt like it was going to up until I tested it, but it doesn't seem sorting will work. The smallest number in the original list does not need to correspond to the smallest number in the test list. I edited my post to show my code attempt.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand it then. Can you show how the first of the long examples works? What are all the correspondences?

Comment: @Barmar I've edited the post with reasonings for each of the longer examples. They all generally refer to the structure laid out in the paragraph above them.

Comment: @Barmar I understand what the original poster was asking for. I think I will edit their question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `all` and `any` with a `zip` with it:

```
>>> l = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [0, 1, 2]]
>>> l2 = [[4, 1], [4, 0], [1, 3], [1, 0], [4, 0, 1]]
>>> all([any(i in x for i in y) for x, y in zip(l, l2)])
True
>>> l3 = [[5, 2], [5, 2], [3, 0], [0, 2], [5, 0, 2]]
>>> all([any(i in x for i in y) for x, y in zip(l, l3)])
False
>>>
```

Comment: This is neat; I'm still wrapping my head around it, but it doesn't work for the second True example. [[1, 2], [3, 1], [2, 4], [1, 4], [2, 4, 1]]

Comment: @jweezy Because the second element of the second example does not have any values in the second element in original list...

Comment: @jweezy By all means it should return `False`

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I double checked that example and it should indeed yield True. 2 is in the sub-list of lenth 3, and it is in 2 of the shorter sub-lists, each time with a different element from the length 3 sub-list. Same goes for 4. 1 is in the length 3 sub-list, and 3 of the shorter sub-lists, 2 of those are paired with other elements from the length 3 sub-list, and the last is when it is paired with the number not in the length 3 sub-list, and that number not in the length 3 sub-list, only appears with the number in 4 total sublists.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve a modified form of what is known as the "[***graph isomorphism problem***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem)." There are existing algorithms which will determine if two graphs are isomorphic, but existing algorithms are all very slow, particularly for large graphs.

"*Graphs*" are diagrams with dots and lines.

Suppose we have two nested lists:

```
L1 = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [0, 1, 2]]
L2 = [[4, 1], [4, 0], [1, 3], [1, 0], [4, 0, 1]]
```

Draw a picture `L1` by from the following instructions:

- For each element of a sublist, draw a dot. For example consider the sublist
  `[0, 1]`. It will get two dots, one dot for `0` and one dot for `1`.
- Draw a circle around a cluster of dots if they are in the same
  sub-list.
- Draw a line between two dots if the two dots represent the same integer.

[image: initial graph]

After that, condense each group of dots (sublist) into a single dot.

[image: condensed graph]

You can draw a similar diagram for nested list `L2` The question is, after you remove the all of the numbers, do the two diagrams for L1 and L2 look the same? You might have to swap the colors around (blue edges become red, red become, blue, etc...) Also the dots might have to be moved around until it looks the same.

The traditional graph isomorphism problem has the lines connecting dots all of the same color. Your problem is slightly different from traditional in that your edges are colored.

I think that you can get rid of the separate colors and simply number each edge with the number of colors that used to be there. It then becomes an "edge-weighted graph"

[image: edge-weighted graph]

Do a google search for "graph isomorphism for edge-weighted graphs."

What you are working on is ***extremely*** difficult. I recommend looking at local university math department websites for people you can contact. Looking for email address of professors whose job title is "graph theorist." Contact them, and ask for their advice.

Like I said, what you are working on is ***extremely*** difficult.

I think that you can solve it as follows:

1. Build the edge-weighted graph for the left list
2. Build the edge-weighted graph for the right list
3. Determine if the two graphs are isomorphic or not.

Comment: Wow thanks for the insight. Seems like a simple problem, but I guess it absolutely isn't. Hmmmm. I'll certainly look into this because it seems fascinating, but are their other ways around this problem? We number things in code all the time and it seems like there are tons of situations where the numbering is arbitrary. What do people do to avoid over-counting? Is it a problem that isn't nearly as common as I am thinking?